# Am I showing the positive-definiteness of a symmetric matrix A correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, positive-definite

A is a 4x4 square, symmetric matrix.  First I computed its Cholesky Decomposition $LL^t$ since the first part of the question asked for it.  Then it asked to show A was positive-definite.  I am a little shaky about some of the last parts of my proof:

For $\vec z$ $\ne$ $\vec 0$, we have that

$$z^tAz$$

$$=z^tLL^tz$$
$$=(z^tL)(L^tz)$$
$$=<(z^tL),(L^tz)>$$
$$=<(z^tL),(z^tL)^t>$$
$$=||z^tL||^2$$
$$=||L^tz||^2$$
$$>0$$

since both $L$ and $L^t$ have trivial null space (both are uni-triangular and invertible), and z was assumed to be a non-zero vector.  Thus the image $L^t(z)$ is not the zero vector, and so the above vector-norm squared is positive, which shows that A is positive-definite.

Is this ok? The last few equalities feel a little awkward.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your arguments are fine.**

The only thing that *might* feel a little awkward is your notation of the inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$:

Obviously it is not the usual dot product of two column vectors since you have the row vector $z^tL$ and the column vector $L^t z$ in there together. What you mean in the 3$^\text{rd}$ line is the usual **matrix product** of an $1\times n$-matrix $a$ and an $n\times 1$-matrix $b$ (usual notation: $ab$) which is the same as taking the **dot product** of the column vectors $a^t$ and $b$ (usual notation: $a^t\cdot b$ or $\langle a^t, b\rangle$). That's probably what you wanted to express in the 4$^\text{th}$ line.

[Note that the matrix product is *not* an inner product in general.]

*Suggestion for a fix:* After your 3$^\text{rd}$ line continue with $$\ldots\\=(z^tL)(L^tz)\\=\langle (z^tL)^t, L^tz\rangle\\=\langle L^tz,L^t z\rangle\\=\lVert L^t z\rVert^2\\>0$$

with the same arguments you gave.

(If you have a different notation for the inner product that allows what you wrote there you probably may discard my concerns.)

Comment: Sorry I haven't logged on in a couple days -- just saw this.  Thanks so much @Piwi :-)